# Не могу подключиться к БД

Tags: sqlite, mysql, java, android, sql

Пытаюсь подключиться к БД, но в коде:

```
try {
               db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d(q,e.toString());
            }
```

Ошибка **java.lang.NullPointerException**, думал может нету БД, так onCreate не вызывается, значит есть БД. в чем может быть проблема?

```
    package com.myapplication15.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBAdapter {
    public static int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public static String DB_Name = "Sources";

    public DBHelper dbHelper;
    public SQLiteDatabase db;
    public Context context;
    public static String TABLE_NAME = "FarmHelper";
    public static String q = "debug";

    public DBAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this.context, DB_Name, null, DB_VERSION);
        Log.d(q, "1");
        try {
            db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(q, e.toString());
        }

    }

    public void getDataBase() {
        Log.d(q, "getDataBase");
        try {
            Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(q,e.toString());
        }

    }
    class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
            super(context, DB_Name, null, DB_VERSION);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
            Log.d(q, "CREATE");
                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE FarmHelper (id integer primary key autoincrement,title text ,status integer,dateadd NUMERIC, priority integer,published integer,uid integer)");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i2) {

        }
    }
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы

```
public SQLiteDatabase db;
```

нигде не инициализируете. Да и строчки:

```
    dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    dbHelper.getDataBase();
```

не имеют смысла

Answer (score 2):

onCreate для вашего хелпера будет вызвана только при отсутствии базы `DB_Name = "Sources"`. Если база существует, то изменить ее можно в onUpgrade при смене версии `DB_VERSION = 1`. Андроид не будет создавать для вас таблицы, если вы просто изменили код в `onCreate`, меняйте версию базы и пишите код в onUpgrade.
Как вариант дропнуть все таблицы, создать заново, вызвав `onCreate`, пока разработка идет с базой можно делать что угодно. Дальше надо уже уметь изменять структуру при выходе новых версий, не удаляя введенные пользователем данные.

> там нету dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

есть, вы отнаследовали ваш хэлпер от SQLiteOpenHelper, у него есть.

Оу, вопрос поменялся.